# Asking "what are your dreams for the future"

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

How does one ask in Mandarin, "what are your dreams" (i.e. future ambitions)

I know that 打算 can be used for if you're planning to do something e.g. 我打算明天去看医生 so am not sure if the phrase would use this or something entirely different like a set phrase

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term 'dream' can be a metaphor for 'goal, hope, or desire' in English. It is the same in Chinese. Therefore, translate 'What are your dreams?' as “你的梦想是什么？” is perfectly appropriate.

梦想 = dream and hope

Comment: Thank you! I'm too new to upvote your answer unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

A few translations (some can only be used in a specific context):
你的志愿是什么? (What is your ambition?)
你对未来的梦想是什么?
你的梦想是什么?
你对未来的期许是什么? (What is/are your hope/hopes for the future?)

Comment: Perhaps OP would also want to know why 打算 is not appropriate in this context?

Comment: 你对未来的打算 means what are your plans for the future?

Comment: Not quite the same

Comment: How about 我打算追逐自己的梦想 by way of contrasting the two terms?

Comment: 我打算追逐自己的梦想 is fine (I plan to chase my dreams)